# How can I create buy offer and sell offer using bitcoin daemon?

Tags: bitcoind, trading, currencies

How do I support trading for multiple crypto coins? Is that possible to create buy or sell offer using bitcoin daemon?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can. There are multiple websites (such as [kraken](https://www.kraken.com/), [btc-e](https://btc-e.com/) and [cryptsy](https://www.cryptsy.com/)) which support API, where you can trade altcoins for BTC or USD/EUR. I am not sure what you mean with a bitcoin daemon, but I think you mean a script or something like that. You can use multiple programming languages  to use the API, as shown on this example page on [kraken](https://www.kraken.com/help/api#example-api-code).

After you got something working, you can trade anything you want, as long as there is a market on the specific exchange site you are using. Good luck!

**edit:**
Ahh I see now what bitcoind is. Of course you can implement this in your script to use for your market strategy, but I don't think you can buy or sell directly from there, as it is not connected to an exchange site.